# Script template to compile a c++ Builder project

Tags: c++builder

I use c++ Builder 2006 (from Borland Developer Studio 2006 Package). How can I compile my project using a script?

I can compile and create my exe File in IDE-enviroment, but I want to do it using a script.

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compiling C++Builder project on command line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4287566/compiling-cbuilder-project-on-command-line)